# Shorten method chaining in Python variable

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
numbers = foo.replace('one', '1').replace('two', '2').replace('three', '3')
```

This is part of a bigger project that takes a list, changes the words to numbers and writes them into one column in a CSV file. My question is if there's a way to shorten the method chaining above. Would a loop be appropriate here?

Comment: Store the mapping in dictionary, replace each key with the corresponding value, assign the value back to the same variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
replacements = [('one', '1'), ('two', '2'), ('three', '3'), ...]
numbers = foo
for item in replacements:
    numbers = numbers.replace(*item)
```

It makes a lot of temporary strings however (as does your chained replace method)

You may also find you have undesired replacements to words like "phone"

If possible you should split your foo into a list of words. Then look up the replacements from a dict

```
replace_dict = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
foo_list = foo.split(' ')
foo = ' '.join(replace_dict.get(k, k) for k in foo_list)
```

Comment: Tried the first method above, and it only changes the last pair.

EDIT: I accidentally put `numbers = foo.replace` instead of what's above. The code works. Thank you!